# What is the exact equivalent of this netsh wlan add filter Windows command for Mac?

Tags: macos, network, bash

I want to block all networks from my PC with admin access and make it so that the user cannot reverse the changes. I will use admin access to only white list certain networks that will be visible to the user and all other WiFi networks are blocked. I am blocking all connections in Windows with the following command. Since I am just starting out with macOS, any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Do you know how to do this graphically on macOS? There’s quite a lot to explain if you’re not sure about admin, GUI firewall, locking down things so we might need to narrow this down a bit. Even if you are new, if you show your research we can often meet you where your experience level is.

Answer (score 6):

> Selecting the option to "Block all incoming connections" prevents all sharing services, such as File Sharing and Screen Sharing from receiving incoming connections.

Start with the firewall general help is my advice.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642

Once you know how those controls work, a follow-on question might work on how to lock this down, whether you use MDM or configuration profile or make a user not an administrator so they can’t change a setting you as the administrator set.

P.S. there is no exact equivalent as the systems are architected differently.

Comment: Selecting the option to "Block all incoming connections" prevents all sharing services, such as File Sharing and Screen Sharing from receiving incoming connections.

It looks like this will only block the apps from receiving a connection, but the WiFi will still be working. I have been doing a little research and I think if there is a way, doing it with a configuration profile will be the way to go for me.

Comment: Exactly @MuhammadHuzaifa you have to be very specific what you want blocked. There is no infrastructure group or `netsh` so you would need to be more detailed on the effect you want on macOS to be achieved. Like if you want to turn off WiFi, that has nothing to do with firewall unless you’re going to start parsing all the possible network adapters.

Comment: If I say that I need to make it so that users cannot connect to any wifi network on MAC unless they have admin access, will you be able to help me set it up? It doesn't have to work the same as netsh

Comment: Absolutely - let’s start a new question with the requirements - post a link to it here and I’ll have a look next time I’m around @MuhammadHuzaifa

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I have posted [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407079/how-can-i-prevent-users-on-mac-from-connecting-to-any-wifi-networks-and-only-con) and will be waiting for your response.