# How can I prevent users on Mac from connecting to any WiFi networks and only connect to white-listed networks?

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I want to make it so that the user cannot connect to any other network other than the specified network. I know I can do this with GUI by removing preferred networks, but this way, I will have to do it for every single one of them. It will be even harder when more networks keep showing up in the networks list.

Is there a method that lets the Mac block every single network and only lets the user connect to specified networks? See the answer in the link below where the guy is doing this through a script for a single network at a time by periodically running the script. Is it possible to do this for all networks?

[How to completely block specific Wi-Fi SSID on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302074/how-to-completely-block-specific-wi-fi-ssid-on-macos/302086)

Comment: If you have only one machine to manage, I still recommend the MDM method, since it's really the best way to script things - but for only one machine you could also make a second account, prevent anyone from knowing the admin password and just lock network preferences entirely. Since you're already scripting, I figured I'd do the pro path for you.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can go with this one for now, and will follow the other method in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to do this with MDM supervision as that’s the easiest way.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-education/choose-a-mobile-device-management-solution-asm1c1be3511/web
- https://www.fleetsmith.com/
- https://app.jamfnow.com/devices

I would start with the free JAMF Now trial since I’ve used it but I hear great things about FleetSmith.

Here is the specific portion of MDM that lets you disable WiFi and push only the approved networks to each managed device.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/server/work-with-configuration-profiles-apddda213639/mac