# wifi setting for mac operating system

Tags: macos, wifi

Would it be possible to hide or disable other ssid for mac operating system? I want to setup only assigned ssid visible for user. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Is removing that control from the menu bar a solution?

Comment: Click on the down arrow will hide them

Comment: I suggest you to look at this nice solution:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/302081/22003

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to hide or disable other ssid for mac operating system? I want to setup only assigned ssid visible for user.

Standard settings only shows Network you are in rage and actively use in Preferred networks.

Other Networks are hidden by default. Only if you click on the Other Networks it will show them. You can hide them again by clicking on Other.

[image: preferred]

[image: Other]

Comment: Thanks, I prefer users can not visible the option, but administrator user can normally.

Comment: @show0116 maybe you can specify that in your question, Even if the other user can see them, he can not do anything without password

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature in macOS. Depending on your goals why you want these hidden, you might have luck saying to auto join the preferred networks, and associate with others but make them off for auto join. You can also try to [script this or set up side loaded configuration profiles](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/302081/5472).

Then when you want to connect, toggle off WiFi and then wait 5 seconds and toggle it on. It will rejoin the best choice of the networks it’s told to auto join.

Another option is to manage your Mac and lock the user out of that control and push profiles to connect to desired networks. [Here’s a start](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407080/5472) down that path.

Comment: Hi Thanks, would it be possible user only can assess assigned SSID, others it not visible or disabled?

Comment: There is no “disable” other than disabling any request to interact with the menu. The OS then joins any of the “approved” SSID by its own measures of fitness. If you need one network primary you have to only provision that one @show0116